# django-modeltranslation removes text from models

Tags: python, django, django-modeltranslation

This is my *translation.py* file:

```
from modeltranslation.translator import translator, TranslationOptions
from polls.models import Question, Choice

class QuestionTranlationOptions(TranslationOptions):
    fields = ('question_text',)

class ChoiceTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
    fields = ('choice_text',)

translator.register(Question, QuestionTranlationOptions)
translator.register(Choice, ChoiceTranslationOptions);
```

*models.py* :

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(_('date published'))
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now
    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = _('Published recently?')

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

When I open the app, the models' text is not visible. One of the questions is "Coke or Sprite?", but I can't see the text. What am I doing wrong?

> Python 3.4,
>   Django 1.10

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user only forgot to read the FineManual before posting...

Answer (score 0):

I had to run this command to fix it:

```
C:\Users\xxx\myproject>manage.py update_translation_fields
```